# How to populate data from a local database in ODK Opendatakit

Tags: android, xml, xforms

I am working on a modification of ODK Opendatakit. ODK uses XFORMS to get input from data and creates an XML instance with data. This instance is then uploaded on the server. What I want to achieve is to auto complete some data from a local database based on an input from the data capturer. For example, if an ID is entered, then that ID is verified from the local database and if it exists, then some pre-defined fields are auto completed. If the ID does not exist, then it given a message to check the ID.

I got the suggestion of using a widget or another app which verifies the entry from a local database and then returns the values of the fields to be completed to the ODK XML instance. What I don't get is how do I pass the values to an instance session in ODK?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the ODK, but I might be able to help with some of the XForms stuff.

XForms data transfer is pretty closely tied to RESTful XML web services. From your description, I'd guess that the interaction pattern would look something like this:

- Create an `input` field for the ID. Store this (and anything other data which needs to go to the server) in the main `instance` of your XForm.
- Create an `action`, bound to either the "xforms-value-changed" or "DOMFocusOut" events on that input field (xforms-value-changed will trigger on every change, whereas DOMFocusOut will only trigger when the user actually leaves the field - which one you use depends on your preferred user experience/server-side capabilities).
- Inside this `action`, run a `submission` to the server, using the main `instance` which contains the ID entered in the input field.
- The server must then respond to this request with an XML document matching your form's schema, with all the required values filled in.
- Have the `submission` set to `replace` the main `instance`.

That's a very high level summary, of course.

The code example here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Suggesting_Items

isn't *exactly* what you're after, but it has many of the same characteristics; enter text into a text field, submit that text to a web service, use the response from the web service to update a model in your form.